# Hourly network device restart using Bash in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, networking, ubuntu, webserver

Ok so this is an odd one. Basically what I'm trying to do is run an infinite loop with a sleep timer that delays the running of a command that restarts the wlan0 network interface. Sounds odd but for some reason the network card stops connecting to the net after about two hours. To cap it all off I'm running a web server for UNI off of it and need to be able to access it remotely. If the connection goes down I'm out of luck. :|

I found this: [Bash "if ping then else" My else is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734238/bash-if-ping-then-else-my-else-is-not-working) which is a much neater way of managing a network interface, only doing the reconfigure when it stops pinging. However this is way over complex. And I did find a few other similar bits of code but they were equally vague.

To be honest I'm a C based programmer. C# C++ and Java at this stage (Python isn't really worth mentioning) anyway I'm having fun just reading bash code let alone modifying a pre-existing snipet. :)

so here's what I'd like to do in sudo code.

```
do {
    sleep 3600s //works
    sudo ifconfig wlan0 down //works in terminal but not script
} while(false);
```

so that's pretty much it. The script is run at start up. Either by the user manually or via the start-up application system. I'd like for it to be automatic but that ifconfig command has to be run as sudo which means running the script as sudo. :)

And tips and/or pointers would be appreciated. I tried the old echo work around for entering the password for sudo but as expected the Ubuntu developers have figured out how to block it.

just found this
[Bash script to bring up and down an interface on loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243845/bash-script-to-bring-up-and-down-an-interface-on-loop)
and this
[Making bash script to check connectivity and change connection if necessary. Help me improve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531583/making-bash-script-to-check-connectivity-and-change-connection-if-necessary-hel)
the second one does what I want but it's running other bash scripts ???? :)

EDIT-1: OK.... well I used Crontab and I think I've got something working I'm not seeing any evidence of it like when I call the sudo ifconfig wlan0 down from commandline. But I'll leave it running tomorrow and see it can keep itself online. :) If not and I'm thinking not what can I do from here?

Incidentally the way ifconfig  down is working on this particular device is that the command takes the device offline after about 20 seconds and then the device switches back on automatically finds the network and reconnects. :) Which courtesy of a IP address bound to the MAC address doesn't cause an issues for me. :)

Comment: ok so looks like we've given up on Bash scripting although it's be nice to do a script but cron seems to work.... except that I don't get the connection lost pop up and searching connected thing on the laptop I'm testing with. :( I'll give it a whirl on the server when I get home. :) ok... went to post this comment and the connection was down.... huh maybe it is working just not auto reconnecting. :)

Comment: see last post for my end comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write a shell script to this that is up to you, but I am a big fan of reusing something that already exists.

Use [cron](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cron) to run your script every hour. Set it up for the root account and have it mess with the interface.

Comment: I noticed others mentioning cron I'll have to have a look at it. :)

Comment: ok wow that was easy. Used www.corntab.com to get me going. :) only one question how do I know it's working and.... as I'm calling ifconfig as sudo will I need to be present to give it a password? or should I just run crontab as sudo to avoid that problem

Answer (score 0):

If you need to avoid password using [sudo](/questions/tagged/sudo), then try this :

```
$ sudo visudo
```

And then, edit to have something like :

```
Host_Alias LOCAL=10.0.0.1 # your own local IP address
user2213541        LOCAL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifconfig
```

---

A simplest way to run commands @start_up is to add a line in `/etc/rc.local`, it will be run as root.

Comment: Added a `A simplest way` to do it.

Comment: ok so that should solve the sudo issue. I'll give it a try. I'm away from the server currently but I've got ubuntu running on my laptop so I'll give it a test run

Comment: ok that's killed my sudo file. Now I can't edit it to change it back! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I accomplished my task using Crontab and the server has remained connected for 7 hours now.

I set owner for crontab as root so that the ifconfig command could be run. I used this script "0 */1 * * * sudo /sbin/ifconfig wlan0 down" and it appears to be working. Now for those trying to do this themselves. You have to be wairy that your network device actually does what mine does. I've got a TP-Link dual band network card. I don't know why but combining this card with ubuntu and this command results in it auto restarting and reconnecting auto-magically.

Your mialage WILL vary. :) I ran this command on my laptop and it didn't restart the network device so... :) yeah be very careful you may want to figure out how to make a matching up command to bring the device but even I had to manually reconnect to the wifi. :| but for this setup, this network device, it works. :)

But yeah. :) Have fun and be careful :)